# Moderate comment plugin without application id?

Tags: comments, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I created a comment plugin from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

It doesn't have an application id. How can I moderate it?

Or if it must have an ID, how do I put an application ID to an existing comment plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your id to your meta data

> To moderate, you need to list yourself as an admin. To do this, simply include open graph meta tags on the URL specified as the href parameter of the plugin. These tags must be included in the  of the document. Include

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

The same process for the app id

> If your site has many comments boxes, we strongly recommend you specify a Facebook app id as the administrator (all administrators of the app will be able to moderate comments). Doing this enables a moderator interface on Facebook where comments from all plugins administered by your app id can be easily moderated together. You can choose to specify either fb:app_id or fb:admins, but not both. This tag should be specified in the .

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

It's all there in the document you linked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: I already tried it, I still don't see any moderation buttons or entries in the the FB moderation page. The thing is, my comment box doesn't have an app ID, I think that's the main issue.

Comment: I already removed it since it didn't work. Besides, what application id will I put since I don't have an application id in the first place?

Comment: @IMB all the information is given above in the answer, if you want to moderate per url add `fb:admins`, if you want to moderate all plugins at once using the moderator tool on Facebook you need an application. In your case the application domain in the app settings would be your main site url `philippine-lotto-results.com`

Comment: The moderation tool doesn't show anything. I only have 2 applications listed and both are not related to this comment box. I tested both of their application IDs (I have one live now using `meta property="fb:app_id"`) but the moderation tool is still empty. So I guess my real problem is I don't really have an application ID for this comment box, how can I get one? I have feeling I've created this comment box before FB required an application ID. I can tell that because when I generate a totally new comment box, it now has an application ID embedded in the code but mine didn't have it.

Comment: @IMB you need to create an application for the domain